# generate class with wsdl with CODE JAVA because i skip certificat

Tags: java, wsdl

I want to write my own code to generate class with wsdl because i use setHostnameVerifier to skip certificat, i have searched since 3 days.

how library i can use to to code inside my class java?

Thanks

Comment: How is "generate class with wsdl" related to "setHostnameVerifier to skip"? What are you actually trying to achieve? It seems to me you are looking for the wrong solution

Comment: Yes i must use setHostnameVerifier, do i need to import src wsimport and change the code?

Comment: Your problem is that the service you are trying to connect communicates over https if I am not wrong. It is easier to download your WSDLs and the referenced XSDs using a browser and generating your classes using the downloaded files. The references of the XSDs in the WSDL files must be updated properly (otherwise your code generation will fail).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question and add a lot more details so someone not familiar with your project understands the problem.

Comment: ok i have the wsdl downloaded, how generating your classes ? without wsimport (because certificat) I don't know why java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching. It is probleme why java client or java server? in the server glassfish i have the good certificat so i conclud the probleme is not the server certi mayv

Comment: "easier " ? how generate without wsimport because "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching nom_server, i don't know if it is client or server probleme never in the forum there precise, i resolve the problem pki in the java/security/cacerts where i exe the ant wsimport not in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
when i get the https: ... wsdl, glassfish domain.xml response with the defaut certificat s1as, there are lots of certificat in the domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks. In the domain.xml there is configur for https listener et ssl with s1as. 
I replace s1as by my certificat that match.